# SPFx extensions will work in SharePoint mobile app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

**Platform:** SharePoint mobile app

This question may sounds silly but need a definite answer. I have created multiple SPFx web parts and added them to pages. These are working fine, when I am trying to see those in SharePoint mobile app (android). But SPFx extensions are not having same behavior.

**Solution background:** 
I am trying to hide the command bar for the modern list due to some security reasons. This is working fine in browser but in SharePoint mobile app, I am still seeing options for the list items like delete, add etc.

**My observations:**
I believe SPFx extension is not working because same elements are not presented in both interfaces.

Command bar in mobile app may be different so it is not working

**Question:**
My observations are right or not?
Is there any way that we can make it work in mobile app also for SPFx extensions?

Comment: were you able to find an answer? I've developed an extension but it is not appearing in SharePoint mobile application